# Looking for Starter Resources for the Soundcloud API in GoLang

Tags: rest, go, soundcloud

I've unsuccessfully tried to access the Soundcloud API with Go. For any language that isn't directly support by Soundcloud, their API is very convoluted. If anyone has any resources or code examples, I'd appreciate it if someone shared them with me.

My code is as follows:

```
func main() {
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("scope", "non-expiring")
    v.Set("client_id", auth.ClientID)
    v.Set("response_type", "code")
    v.Set("redirect_uri", auth.RedirectURI)

    c.AuthURL = AuthEndpoint + "?" + v.Encode()
    c.Values = v.Encode()

    res := c.Request("POST", url.Values{})
}



func (c *Client) Request(method string, params url.Values) []byte {
    params.Set("client_id", "*************")

    reqUrl := "https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token"

    req, _ := http.NewRequest(method, reqUrl, strings.NewReader(c.Values))
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    resp, _ := c.client.Do(req)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    return body
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at [yanatan16/golang-soundcloud](https://github.com/yanatan16/golang-soundcloud), even though then authentication part isn't implemented yet ([see issues](https://github.com/yanatan16/golang-soundcloud/issues))

There is an [oauth class](https://github.com/yanatan16/golang-soundcloud/blob/master/soundcloud/oauth.go) though.
Ad quite a few other calls to the API, for getting SoundCloud objects.

Answer (score 1):

i'm active developing a package in go to access/work with Soundcloud API, it has OAuth2 support, and is already usable.

I invite you to look for it. https://github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud

Take in consideration that the package is still under heavy development, the API might change in the future.

Comment: That looks interesting (more advanced than the ones I mentioned in my answer). +1